# Python SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escap

Tags: python

Does anyone know why I am getting this unicode error. I am trying to remove duplicates from a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('new.csv', usecols=['minzoom', 'maxzoom']).drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index()
file_name = "C:\Users\kziaj\Desktop\Python Test\newno.csv"
df.to_csv("newno.csv", index=False) # you don't need to set sep in this because to_csv makes it comma delimited.
```

Comment: Show us how your `new.csv` looks like?

Comment: name,number
aa,1
ab,1
aa,1
ab,2
aa,34
ab,1
ab,25
asd,123
asd,11
aa,1
ab,1
aa,1
ab,2
aa,34
ab,1
ab,25
asd,123
asd,11
aa,1
ab,1
aa,1
ab,2
aa,34
ab,1
ab,25
asd,123
asd,11

Comment: I cant add a new line on this but after every number is a new line.

Comment: Update the example in the question for better readability please!

Answer (score 9):

The error indicates the path of your file is not valid.
Specifically, python treats single backslash as escape character, not a path separator, which is a common mistake in python programming on Windows. To avoid this, use double backslash or raw string.

**Double Backslash**

```
file_name = "C:\\Users\\kziaj\\Desktop\\Python Test\\newno.csv"
```

**Raw String**

```
file_name = r"C:\Users\kziaj\Desktop\Python Test\newno.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your csv file has some non-ascii characters in it. I tried your code and it worked fine. Just try creating a new csv file and try it

> new.csv

```
name,number
aa,1
ab,1
aa,1
ab,2
aa,34
ab,1
ab,25
asd,123
asd,11
aa,1
ab,1
aa,1
ab,2
aa,34
ab,1
ab,25
asd,123
asd,11
aa,1
ab,1
aa,1
ab,2
aa,34
ab,1
ab,25
asd,123
asd,11
```

Then I ran your code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('new.csv').drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index()
print(df)
df.to_csv("newno.csv", index=False)
```

And the output comes out as

> newno.csv

```
index,name,number
0,aa,1
1,ab,1
3,ab,2
4,aa,34
6,ab,25
7,asd,123
8,asd,11
```

Comment: Hi I tried creating a new csv file and I still get the same error.

Comment: Just copy paste the content from the answer into the csv file, that is what I did to create my answer!